# How to Customize Humanized Moment js Date Result

Tags: momentjs

I want to customize the humanize date result with moment js. Let's say I have a date and I want to take the remaining time that return back a result "in 3 months"

```
moment("20141001", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // in 3 months
```

How can I customize the resultant string like `3 months left` ? Is moment provide any external parameter to customize the resultant or any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Like moment#fromNow, passing true as the second parameter returns value without the suffix. This is useful wherever you need to have a human readable length of time."

[Moment documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

So,

```
var start = moment([2007, 0, 5]);
var end = moment([2007, 0, 10]);
start.from(end);                   // "in 5 days"
start.from(end, true);             // "5 days"
start.from(end, true) + " left";   // "5 days left"
```

Comment: I am running into an issue. Could you please help me again. I have an incoming date from server 2014-07-01T15:30:00Z  and I want to take difference from the current time. How can I make it possible, I just can not be able to get the exact difference.

Comment: See this question for how to parse a string into a moment:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093796/date-formatting-with-without-moment-js

Comment: See this question for how to perform math on moments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428656/subtract-time-from-date-moment-js