# Display day with hours in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

Here are date and time.

```
Date 2018-05-25T10:35:04.000Z
```

Expected Output = **3 days 12 hours**

I want to display date and time same like as a give above. Currently, I am using `moment.js`. Is there any way to display like above?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Zvi's suggestion, you could use the [AngularJS date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Say in your controller you have 2 dates:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    ctrl = this;

    ctrl.date1 = new Date("2018-05-22T22:35:04.000Z");
    ctrl.date2 = new Date("2018-05-25T10:35:04.000Z");
});
```

And in HTML, you'd display the difference with the date filter:

```
{{ctrl.date2 - ctrl.date1 | date:"dd 'days' HH 'hours'"}}
```

Here's a working [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/mqbdLezh/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it is not working.

Can you please try below 2 dates:


ctrl.date1 = new Date("2018-05-22T22:35:04.000Z");
    
    ctrl.date2 = new Date("2018-05-22T10:35:04.000Z")

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't work when ctrl.date1 > ctrl.date2 because we're performing subtraction of date1 from date2

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [moment-precise-range](https://github.com/codebox/moment-precise-range).

Here's full example:

```
calcDiff = (date : string) => {
    let diff_in_string = '';
    let original_date = moment(date);
    let date_time_now = moment();
    let diff_in_object: any = moment-presice.preciseDiffBetweenDates(original_date, date_time_now, true);
    if (diff_in_object.days > 0) {
        diff_in_string = diff_in_string + diff_in_object.days + ' ';
        if (diff_in_object.days === 1) {
            diff_in_string += 'Day '
        } else {
            diff_in_string += 'Days '
        }
    }
    if (diff_in_object.hours > 0) {
        if (diff_in_object.days > 0) {
            diff_in_string += 'and ' + diff_in_object.hours + ' '
        } else {
            diff_in_string += diff_in_object.hours + ' '
        }
        if (diff_in_object.hours === 1) {
            diff_in_string += 'Hour '
        } else {
            diff_in_string += 'Hours '
        }
    }
    diff_in_string += 'ago'
    return diff_in_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using The [HumanizeDuration](https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js) library (you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24509729/922977)).
It allows you to translate in any language you want the difference between two dates the way you want.

For example :

```
var yourdate= moment().set({'year': 2018, 'month': 5, 'day': 22});
var today = moment();
var duration = moment.duration(today.diff(yourdate));
var humanized = humanizeDuration(duration, { units: ['d', 'h'], language: language, round: true });
```

You can also format it with spacers, etc.