# How to subtract time using moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have start and end dates in my component which I am getting using `moment` library through the time picker.

So suppose my datepicker selects startDate and endDate for the today. Now I need another  dates let's say `previousStartDate` and `previousEndDate`  which should be the same time difference  compared to `startDate` and `endDate`.

```
startDate = '20-06-2019 00:00:00'
endDate = '20-06-2019 23:59:59'
```

So the `previousStartDate` and `previousEndDate` should be

```
previousStartDate = '19-06-2019 00:00:00'
previousEndDate = '19-06-2019 23:59:59'
```

How can do that?

I have tried this but with no success

```
  getPreviousStartDates ({ startDate, endDate }) {
     const diff = endDate.diff(startDate)
     const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff)
     const subtractStartDate = startDate.subtract(diff)
     console.log({subtractStartDate})
     return subtractStartDate
  }
```

Some more clarification

Suppose The time difference between the `startDate` and `endDate` is 3 days `(17-6-2019 00:00:00 && 19-6-2019 23:59:59)` then the time difference between `previousStartDate` and `previousEndDate` should be the same but past 3 days. `(14-6-2019 00:00:00 && 16-6-2019 23:59:59)`

Comment: Why don't you just return both dates (`startDate` and `endDate`) minus 1 day ?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428656/subtract-time-from-date-moment-js) should answer your question

Comment: There is some information missing here... Can you explain precisely how you want previousStartDate and previousEndDate to be computed?

Comment: @BJRINT `startDate` and `endDate` can be changed. What ever the difference I get from the timepicker I need to subtract same from the `previousStartDate` and `previousEndDate`

Comment: @Keilath Suppose The time difference between the `startDate` and `endDate` is 3 days `(17-6-2019 00:00:00 && 19-6-2019 23:59:59)` then the time difference between `previousStartDate` and `previousEndDate` should be the same but past 3 days. `(14-6-2019 00:00:00 && 16-6-2019 23:59:59)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a requirement that it is done using momentjs? I'm not so familiar with momentjs, but you could do it in javascript like this:

```
let start = new Date("2019-06-20 00:00:00");
let end = new Date("2019-06-20 23:59:59");
let duration = end.getTime() - start.getTime(); // milliseconds

let prevStart = new Date(start.getTime() - duration);
let prevEnd = new Date(prevStart.getTime() + duration);
```

Comment: *I'm not so familiar with momentjs* No problem Thank you for the answer. I will check and accept it.