# how to change a value of a date from ("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss") to ("mm") in an user provided value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the user provide value is 
`var date = 2019/11/06 22:59:50;`
 but i want to convert the data of **date** as 
`date = 55;` 
from ("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss") to ("mm") 
having only the minute  so that i can  subtract the data as `alert(date - Date().getMinute())` so that i can save the value to a variable for conditions

Comment: Can you use a library or would the solution have to be without one?

Comment: Do you mean `date = 59;`?

Comment: yes i mean date = 59

Comment: ya you can use **library ** as will for the solution

Comment: `.getMinutes()` will give you the minute component only, not the date in minutes - *this is of no use to you for comparison*.   eg 18:04 -> 04, 17:59 -> 59 - compare 04 with 59?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I subtract minutes from a date in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674721/how-do-i-subtract-minutes-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Date manipulation is really rough in JS. If you can ensure the format is going to be exactly like that, you can do something like this:

```js
var date_raw = "2019/11/06 22:59:50";
var date = new Date(date_raw);
var mm = date.getMinutes();
```

Otherwise, I suggest you look into [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) if you need something more complex.

**Edit**: if you're just looking for help on subtracting time from a date object, [that's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674721/how-do-i-subtract-minutes-from-a-date-in-javascript) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428656/subtract-time-from-date-moment-js)

Comment: i have just started javascript

Comment: No problem! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if that's everything you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, in first place I would transform the date var into a Date object, like this: `var date = new Date("2019/11/06 22:59:50");`. Then I'd add a min var that would take the mm part of the date like this: `var min = date.getMinutes();`. That would do the job.